# Sort & filter buttons are (suddenly) not available in Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel Table (created by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), where filter buttons are added by default. But suddenly they disappeared and the checkbox for switching them on/off is greyed out.

There are two other tables in same sheet and they work properly. I can't figure what causes this behavior.

Sceenshot: [image]

Copying sheet to another/new workbook doesn't help. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Do you group the table? If yes, please ungroup it.

Comment: No, any groups in this table (do you think this [Office help page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff)?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue. When I turned "header row" off and on again they reappeared. (Yes I am congnizant of the fact that it sounds like a fix to every other MS apps issue... but it actually worked for me.)

Answer (score 2):

Select all of the headers,  go to Home>Sort & filter> and make sure the filter button is selected in this option. That should fix it for you